# Как задать направление движения объекта в 2d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать передвижение объекта по waypoint'ам. Откопал вот такой код

```
 public GameObject[] waypoints;
  .....
  private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     float dist = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, waypoints[current].transform.position);
     if (chill)
     {
         if (dist > mindist)
         {
             move();
         }
         else
         {
             if (!rand)
             {
                 if (current + 1 == waypoints.Length)
                 {
                     current = 0;
                 }
                 else { current++; }

             }
             else
             {
                 current = Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
             }
         }
     }
         }
```

Вот только метод move() в нём был заточен под 3d пространство,  с использованием LookAt и transform.forward . А чем заменить их в 2d?

```
public void move()
    {
        gameObject.transform.LookAt(waypoints[current].transform.position);
        gameObject.transform.position += gameObject.transform.forward * 2f * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Comment: Что же мешает вам писать 0 во все координаты Z и не обращать на Z внимание?

Comment: Отсутствие понимания того, что такое оси координат

Comment: @nick_n_a а каким образом это можно сделать? Пожалуйста, напишите в ответе.

Comment: А где код `move()`? Это ж самое главное

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в вопрос оригинальный код move()

Comment: А вы пробовали его применять как есть? По идее, он и так должен работать

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел, как он работает. Во-первых, объект немного проваливается по оси z и это число постоянно варьируется. И движется он только к первому вэйпоинту, после чего застревает там, пытаясь совершить что-то непонятное мне. +LookAt наклоняет спрайт

Comment: Да, ненмого наврал. Forward - это про трёхмерное пространство. Доберусь до компьютера - пороюсь

Comment: У вас в игре проекция какая? Скриншот можете показать?

Comment: Имеете ввиду камеру? Ортографическая. А чего именно скриншот нужен?

Comment: Если заменить `Vector3.Distance` на `Vector2.Distance` , а `gameObject.transform.forward` на `gameObject.transform.right` что-нибудь хорошее произойдет? или `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[current].transform.position, 2f * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: Во! `MoveTowards` - то, что нужно! Благодарю.

Comment: @FullyRetarded И `LookAt`, кстати, можно смело убирать. Нужно убирать.

Comment: Да, я убрал уже.

Comment: @eastwing ,  FullyRetarded на самом деле, даже код, который у вас в вопросе должен отрабатывать корректно. Я, честно говоря не понял в чем проблема у вас возникла......а `LookAt` это зависит от того, нужно ли, чтоб перемещаемый объект смотрел на `waypoint` или нет... может это платформа, тогда надо было убрать, если персонаж, то не надо (если не задумано обратное)....... крч... я не одуплил) проблемы и так не должно быть xD

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я делаю topdown 2d игру. Мне не нужно, чтобы объекты вращались или находились под каким-либо углом, а LookAt наклоняла объект. (=